# colums will not stay in line with wysiwyg editor

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, shortcode

could someone give me a hand with this please, a wysiwyg editor in Wordpress is giving me a headache when it comes to the layout of 3 simple columns!

here is the page, as you can see the colums seem to dip with each one and i cant see what ive done wrong or what the editor is putting in!!

http://zonedigital.ie/pharmatherm/?page_id=6494

here is the source code:

```html
<div class="one_third first_column"><img class="textmiddle alignleft" src="http://zonedigital.ie/pharmatherm/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Adobe-Acrobat-icon-150x150.png" alt="Adobe-Acrobat-icon" width="20" height="20" /> Document 1</p>
<img class="textmiddle alignleft" src="http://zonedigital.ie/pharmatherm/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Adobe-Acrobat-icon-150x150.png" alt="Adobe-Acrobat-icon" width="20" height="20" /> Document 2

</div>
<div class="one_third second_column">
<p style="text-align: left;"><img class="textmiddle alignleft" src="http://zonedigital.ie/pharmatherm/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Adobe-Acrobat-icon-150x150.png" alt="Adobe-Acrobat-icon" width="20" height="20" /> Document 3</p>
<img class="textmiddle alignleft" src="http://zonedigital.ie/pharmatherm/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Adobe-Acrobat-icon-150x150.png" alt="Adobe-Acrobat-icon" width="20" height="20" /> Document 4

</div>
<div class="one_third third_column">
<p style="text-align: left;"><img class="textmiddle alignleft" src="http://zonedigital.ie/pharmatherm/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Adobe-Acrobat-icon-150x150.png" alt="Adobe-Acrobat-icon" width="20" height="20" /> Document 5</p>
<img class="textmiddle alignleft" src="http://zonedigital.ie/pharmatherm/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Adobe-Acrobat-icon-150x150.png" alt="Adobe-Acrobat-icon" width="20" height="20" /> Document 6

</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the line breaks (`<br>` tags) between your columns. Maybe switch your editor to plain text to do this.

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, there is a `<br>` between each column.